# The entity type Employee is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am facing this issue,I gone through several posts,pls reply me how to resolve this.
the below is my code

**controller class**

in this third line I am getting error :

> The entity type Employee is not part of the model for the current
> context

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  MvcApplication6.Models.EmployeeContext employeeContext = new MvcApplication6.Models.EmployeeContext();
  MvcApplication6.Models.Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.Id == id);
  return View(employee);
}
```

**EmployeeContext class**

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }       
}
```

**Model Class**

```
namespace MvcApplication6.Models
{
     [Table("tblEmployee")]
     public class Employee
     {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
     }
}
```

**Entity Data model name** `Employee.edmx`

Comment: Does it work if  you remove the `[Table("tblEmployee")]` attribute? Can you share your edmx file?

Comment: I removed [Table("tblEmployee")] attribute still same error

Comment: edmx file having Employee table with Id,Name,Gender,City columns

Comment: What are you doing with that entity in the View?

Comment: displaying the table data i.e id,name,gender,city values

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the Entity Framework and generating the model from the database, take the entity that is ‘not part of the model’ and view it using the Model/Entity Diagram (*.edmx). Right click, and Validate. Next, Save and Build.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

It may occur because:

- `DbContext` configured with an incorrect `connection string`
- The entity specified is actually not mapped in `configuration`